# Infinite loop while calling method inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to call a method that pushes data into array, but the datas I've inserted are redundant and i got this warning:

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

Here's my code:

```
<v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="i in 12" :key="i">
     {{ pushShow(i) }}
</v-flex>
.
.
.
.
methods: {
   pushShow(i){
      this.show.push(i);

    }
}
```

I'm going to show cards which are having different behaviour according to the data inside the array, so the array would be like: [true, true, false, false, etc]

How can I resolve this problem? thanks for advance

Comment: It's simple. __Never update your data from template/render function!__

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that it will be called every time a re-rendering occurs for your loop. If you want to, you can describe your goal that you want to achieve in detail and we might be able to hint you to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `pushShow(i)` in your template, and that method is performing `this.show.push(i)` which is mutating your data. This will trigger another render because Vue has detected a change in the data, which will call `pushShow(i)` *again*, and so on forever.

You need to make sure you do not mutate any data during a render. If you can provide some more details about what you are trying to achieve, we can give you a solution to your problem.